# jmp-pop-call tecnique with stdin

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, system-calls, shellcode

I have written this code as an exercise to practice with jmp-pop-call shellcoding tecnique:

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
    jmp call_shellcode

shellcode:
    pop rsi
    ;sys_write syscall
    xor rax, rax
    mov al, 1
    xor rdi, rdi
    mov dil, 1
    xor edx, edx
    mov dl, 18
    syscall
    jmp call_shellcode2

shellcode2:
    pop rsi
    ;sys_red syscall
    xor rax, rax
    xor rdi, rdi    
    mov edx, 4
    syscall

    ; exit syscall
    xor rax, rax
    mov al, 60 ;mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi ;mov rdi, 0
    add dil, 0
    syscall

call_shellcode:
    call shellcode
    welcome: db 'Insert password: ', 0xa

call_shellcode2:
    call shellcode2
    input: db 0xffffffff
```

The problem is the following:

```
$ ./simple_shellcode
Insert password: 
abc
$ abc
bash: abc: command not found
```

It seems that when I hit enter, the value that I inserted (plus enter) is passed to the shell. I can't understand why this happened...

Can you try to explain me the problem?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Here, the `strace` output:

```
execve("./BindShell", ["./BindShell"], 0x7fff3b5e0d00 /* 49 vars */) = 0
write(1, "Insert password: \n", 18Insert password: 
)     = 18
read(0, 123 
0x40104f, 4)                    = -1 EFAULT (Invalid address)
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

As Peter Cordes said in the comments the `read` function returns `-1 EFAULT` and assembling it with `--omagic` option it works fine. 
Now my question is: is a clean solution use that option using jmp-pop-call technique?

Comment: Well first observation is that you can use RIP relative addressing in 64-bit code so you don't need to use JMP call POP although you do need to place the data before it is referenced and JMP over it.

Comment: But I assume that the problem here lies in the way you build this code and that your `.text` section isn't writeable. Can you show us the commands you use to assemble and link. I suspect if you test tis code by running your program with `strace` you'd discover that the address for SYS_Input is invalid and the syscall returned with an error.

Comment: If you use `nasm -f elf64 test.asm -o test.o`  to assemble you can link with LD using  `ld test.o -o test --omagic` (you can replace `--omagic` with `-N` as well) . This example uses the name `test`. That can be changed to the file name you use.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers... @Michael Petch what does --omagic option do?

Comment: Among other things it makes the `.text` section writeable.

Comment: Use `strace  ./simple_shellcode` to see what your program actually did.  Presumably `sys_read` returned with -EFAULT instead of reading anything, because you tried to use a static buffer in `.text` instead of simply using stack space like a normal person.  The initial contents of your buffer appear meaningless, so IDK why you want a static buffer in your shellcode.

Comment: Yesterday, I saw that `sys_read` returns -14 in `rax`. Tonight, I'll edit my question with `strace` output.

Comment: `-EFAULT` is `-14`.  That's what happens if you pass sys_read an address that isn't writable.  Allocating stack space with `lea rsi, [rsp -128]` or something is the obvious solution, instead of padding your shellcode with space for the buffer.

Comment: (If you trace the chain of `#include` files, it's defined in `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h`, which glibc gets from Linux kernel headers.)

Comment: @PeterCordes you are saying that I have to change under shellcode2 `pop rsi` with `lea rsi, [rsp - n]`?

Comment: You don't *have* to, but that change makes it obviously better in every way, because you don't need a jmp/call/pop or anything, just point the register at some stack space.  `add rsp, -128` / `mov rsi,rsp` would work, too, but you don't need that.  It's safe to use up to 128 bytes below RSP in x86-64 System V.  Look at optimized gcc output for a function containing `volatile char buf[64] = {0};` or something.